# Does Bing Search API use Bing index?

Tags: bing, bing-api

How can I make site that will be correclty found by Bing API, but will be invisible for Bing, Google, Yandex and so on?

Comment: You block everything but Bing using robots.txt. As for making it API-only... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the same index that powers the Bing site also powers the Bing Search API.

So far as I can guess/expect, there isn't a way for a site to show up in one set of results and not in another.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about Bing but with Google the results can differ a LOT.
The order of results is different for several reasons. One obvious reason is that their result-order is the source of their success. 

So the API of a search engine usually gives you results but a wrong order which might also mean that your site is or is not inside the "organic result pages", regardless if it's in the API results you received.

If you want ot make sure you need to parse the organic pages just like a browser does.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make a result invisible to Bing Index, but still make it available in the Bing APIs. If you can tell me more about what your scenario is and why you want this experience, probably I can help more.